# Trying to put multiple data in php/json array

Tags: php, arrays, json

This is probably quite simple to do.. but I just can't think of how to do this.

I have a photo upload script, I want to return two types of data in an array, right now I just have one set of data for the photo returned.

right now I do this:

```
 $photos = array();

 ///Script for photo upload etc.
 array_push($photos, $newPhotoToAdd)

 //then when it's finished uploading each photo i do json_encode:
 print json_encode($photos);
```

all of this works perfect, however now I want to return another set of data with each photo.

I need to do something like:

```
 array_push($photos, ['photoID'] = $photoID, ['photoSource'] = $newPhotoToAdd)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Original Question

You can just push an array on instead of `newPhotoToAdd` like the following:

```
$photos = array();
// perform upload
$photos[] = array(
    'photoID' => $photoID,
    'photoSource' => $newPhotoToAdd
);
print json_encode($photos);
```

You'll notice that I have swapped [`array_push()` <sup>DOCs</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) for the [array append syntax of `[]` <sup>DOCs</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) as it is simpler and with less overhead:

> **Note:** If you use array_push() to add one element to the array it's
>   better to use $array[] = because in that way there is no overhead of
>   calling a function.

### From comments: printing it out in JavaScript

You are dealing with an array of objects so you need to loop over them:

```
for(var i in json) {
    alert(json[i].photoID);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, now I'm having trouble trying to use this in javascript though. It's not working as I thought it would.

    var json = JSON.parse(content);
alert(json.photoID);

this returns undefined

Answer (score 0):

You want to create an array like this:

```
$photo = array('photoID' => $photoID, 'photoSource' => $newPhotoToAdd);
```

Then you want to do the push as you did before with this new array:

```
array_push($photos, $photo);
```

Answer (score 0):

do something like:

```
$photos = array();
array_push($photos, array('photoID'=>$photoID,'photoSource'=>$newPhotoToAdd));

foreach ($photos as $photo) {
print json_encode($photo);
}
```